# 404 page cannot be found error in wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I m facing very weird problem in wordpress wp-admin. I was trying to upload image to the post and i encountered a problem. I turned on firebug and saw http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=36671 is not found (404 error), 
Addtionally, 
http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/ajax-admin.php is not found as well [in firebug]

actually the file DOES EXIST in the right folder in the server. I then edited this file put following lines at top of the page

```
echo "Hello World";
exit;
```

Now the file is found. Can anybody suggest a solution? My wordpress version is 3.3.1

**THE ISSUE CREATOR.**

The problem creator line was do_action('admin_init');
i commented line do_action('admin_init'); in admin.php now everything works except that ADMIN design is messed up.
Any Help will be appreciated.

EDIT :
I turned on WP_DEBUG, And i just see Notices, 500s of them, I don't see any other warnings or errors.

Thanks
Sabin

Comment: Can you turn wp-config debug on ? and see what error display ?

Comment: I could see tons of errors in the page, And most of them I don't understand. Shall I post errors here?

Comment: Didnt let me Edit so adding new comment

EDIT :
Those were just Notices, 500s of them, I don't see any other warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem doing following stuffs.

I commented 
do_action('admin_init'); on admin.php in wp-admin folder.

This messed up the admin design, then I added following lines in my theme's functions.php

```
function itg_admin_css_all_page() {

wp_register_style($handle = 'itg-admin-css-all', $src = "/wp-admin/css/colors-classic.css", $deps = array(), $ver = '1.0.0', $media = 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('itg-admin-css-all');
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'itg_admin_css_all_page');
```

And this solved the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

- I think something went wrong with your **function.php** file , check if there is any whitespaces on the top or bottom of the page ?
- Just turn wp-config debug on and see what errors you are getting ?
- Did you try to change name of any function ?
- More , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40149/wp-admin-page-is-blank see this , sure it will help you.
- http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-options-page-not-found-please-help-to-figure-out

Good luck..

Comment: Well, Previously it was working before update to 3.3.1, havent changed anything in functions.php. And there are no whitespaces in the functions.php. The links you've given me doesnot work for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem also, I even did a fresh WordPress install and was still having it. All you need to do is upgrade your PHP version.

I went to my control panel and in the software/services section there's a button that says php configuration, when you click on that a little drop down menu appears and there you can chose the latest version of PHP, which I was on 5.2 and upgraded it to 5.5. When I did that the 404 errors went away.